# " No such module 'FirebaseFirestore' "after adding references inside pod file

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I trying to build my app, but I receiving an error : No such module 'FirebaseFirestore'. It happens when I try to make connection to my database.

[Error with app code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsG0C.png)

I found some solution to update pod file with 'Firebase/Firestore" and 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', but this does not help, error still occurs after successful pod install.

[Pod file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUbot.png)

Somebody know how to fix this issue and make connection to DB?

Comment: uncomment the `platform:ios,9.0 ` in line no 2. Then open the `xcworksplace` instead of `xcodeproj`

Comment: @Dilan now im getting two errors: First in all view controllers files at 'import Firebase' - **Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'** . And second error inside Firebase.h file : **'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found** . I tried to update podfile with adding pod 'Firebase/Core", but it doesn't help.

Comment: first change `platform:ios,9.0` to `platform:ios,11.0`. Then copy paste your all pods to line no 6. you add the pods out of project scope.

Comment: Thanks, after deleting old pod files and doing your steps, it working.

Comment: Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Select `Clean Project` and then write `pod install` on the terminal